# sqlite.bz2 File does not match checksum - centos 5.7

Tags: checksum

I have tried absolutely everything, without good results...

yum always fails with "sqlite.bz2 File does not match checksum" for different repositories, every single time, but always with the above error.

ive tried setting ...
* http_proxy
* http_caching
* disabling fastestmirror
* changing settings in sysctl.conf

all with the same result,

Im starting to think it might be a bug?...related to http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=5116

Comment: Are you behind a proxy of some kind?

Comment: i face this problem, in my case because of my IPS/Firewall, somehow yum always failed if IPS enabled. not sure if it's same like you or not.

Answer (score 2):

As ive read this on another website while searching for the answer to this.
The OP states 'different repositories', so it matches my difficulties as well, trying to install centos 6.2 in a directory on redhat 5.3.

The thing is that the python version of different release is different.

> Python 2.6 uses hashlib to perform checksums, and Python 2.4 uses the SHA module to perform checksums. The version of the SHA module that ships with CentOS 5.3 doesn’t support sha256, which is why we get the checksum error listed above

from : http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2009/11/26/dealing-with-yum-checksum-errors/

Answer (score 1):

The version of yum on CentOS 5 does not support the default checksum method used by CentOS 6. If you are trying to install from a repository that you control you may regenerate the repository meta information with the `createrepo` command, using the `--checksum "sha"` option. From the createrepo man page:

> -s --checksum
>         Choose the checksum type used in repomd.xml and for packages in the metadata.  The default is
>         now  "sha256" (if python has hashlib). The older default was "sha", which is actually "sha1",
>         however explicitly using "sha1" doesnât work on older (3.0.x) versions of yum,  you  need  to
>         specify "sha".